# Dynamic 2D array elements are not accessible several for loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I've studied data structure and algorithm, and I got a problem with dynamic 2d array. Here is part of my code. The coding problem is the Knight's tour.

```
int iMove[8] = {-2, -1, 1, 2, 2,  1, -1, -2};
int jMove[8] = { 1,  2, 2, 1,-1, -2, -2, -1};


cell* cellList(int* i, int* j, int** board){
    int k;
    cell* temp;
    int iTempNext; int jTempNext;
    int maxSampleNum = 8;
    int cnt = 0;    
    int val;

    for(k = 0; k < maxSampleNum; k++){
        iTempNext = (*i) + iMove[k];
        jTempNext = (*j) + jMove[k];

        //1. get list 0<=i<=7 && 0<=j<=7
        if( (0 <= iTempNext && iTempNext <= 7) && (0 <= jTempNext && jTempNext <= 7)){
        //2. get the 0 value cells
            //val = canMove(iTempNext, jTempNext, board);
            printf("%d %d\n", iTempNext, jTempNext);
            if(board[iTempNext][jTempNext] == 0){
                cell tempCell;
                tempCell.row = iTempNext;
                tempCell.col = jTempNext;
                temp = (cell*)realloc(temp, sizeof(cell));
                *(temp+cnt) = tempCell;
                cnt++;

            }

        }

    }

    return temp;
}
```

int** board : 2d array and I allocated it dynamically and initialized all elements of this array to 0. I printed 2d array after initializing.
The problem is that after 2nd for loop, this program got segmentation fault on accessing 2d array. I cannot access 2d array elements during 3rd for loop.

```
Initializing Complete...                                                                                                                                                               
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                                        
Enter the start position (i, j): 3 3  
iTempNext jTempNext                                                                                                                                             
1           4                                                                                                                                                                                    
2           5                                                                                                                                                                                    
4           5                                                                                                                                                                                    

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                                                                                   
0x0000000000400b1c in cellList (i=0x7fffffffe5bc, j=0x7fffffffe5c0, board=0x603010) at main.c:144                                                                                      
144                             if(board[iTempNext][jTempNext] == 0){
```

this is the result after using gdb. How can I solve this problem

Comment: Post your other functions please and create a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: `iMove[k]` and `jMove[k]`, where do these values come from??

Comment: @user3121023 thanks for your advice. I get lesson that using 'realloc()' carefully. I just checked 'temp' space cover other memory space after several 'realloc'. I change my logic to get the expected length of array and 'malloc()' it.

Comment: @Magisch I will post question more specifically next time.

Comment: @CrakC the top of 1st code box

Comment: @JSKIM Alright, your problem seems to have been resolved. Please post the code that solved your problem so that the question can be closed.

Comment: The question is about a runtime problem.   Therefore, the posted code needs to be minimal, compile cleanly and display the problem,.   The posted code does not compile cleanly.  and is not runable.  strongly suggest posting code that does compile cleanly so we can test it to find the problem.

Comment: the local variable pointer `temp` has not been initialized to anything in particular, so contains trash.   Passing that pointer to realloc() will corrupt the heap.

Comment: temp = (cell*)realloc(temp, sizeof(cell)); 1) will be modifying an uninitialised pointer. suggest initializing the pointer to NULL. 2) in C, the returned value from realloc() is a void * so can be assigned to any other pointer, so no need to cast it and casting it makes for headaches when performing maintenance and/or debugging. 3) the realloc() function can fail. Then the code is trashing the original ptr to memory. Always check (!=NULL) before assigning to the original pointer

Comment: Thanks for every advice! I just completed to create Knight' tour algorithm. I change `cell* cellList(int* i, int* j, int ** board)` to `cell* cellList(int* i, int* j, int** board, int nPos)`. `int nPos` is the number of elements which `cell* temp` will get dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
temp = (cell*)realloc(temp, sizeof(cell));
```

invokes **undefined behaviour** since `temp` is not initialized. You should initialize it with, e.g., `cell *temp = NULL;` (understand that `realloc` can either take a `NULL` pointer in which case it is equivalent to `malloc`, or a previously `malloced/calloced/realloced` pointer).

And **don't cast the return from malloc**. This is C, not C++. Search this site for why casting the `malloc` return value is frowned upon in C.

Comment: As your advice, I initialized `cell* temp = NULL`, and it made me easily figure out the array is NULL or not. This made my code avoid run time error.

Comment: @JSKIM Glad to hear it. Now the next step on Stack Overflow is to *accept* an answer by clicking the check mark under the arrows to the left. This will earn you 2 credits.